# How can I force prefix "pg_" to create new user in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I have problem with postgres. It is possible to force prefix "pg_" to create user in PostgreSQL? For example:

```
CREATE USER pg_admin PASSWORD 'qwerty';
```

I am using PostgreSQL 10.6

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The `pg_` prefix is typically reserved for system owned and managed things. I would never name _anything_ that is user created with the `pg_` prefix

Comment: I'm working on an old project where we're doing the migration to another server. In my sql backups i have this user then i have to create it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This limitation has been in effect since version 9.6, where system roles starting with `pg_` were introduced.

You *could* create a role with a different name and then update `rolname` in `pg_authid`, but that would be a bad idea, since PostgreSQL treats such roles differently than others. For example, the role would not be dumped by `pg_dumpall -r`.

Comment: This way don`t help me but thank you for the answer. I solved my problem by replacing the name in the backup files, so I didn't need that prefix anymore.